# Unhandled issue when using the clearInterval func in an `onClick` event in the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setinterval, clearinterval

Please understatnd that this is the first post.

I'm developing a dashboard. But there's a problem.

I used to use setInterval, but I wrote a code that performs clearInterval when I press the button.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const testInterval = () => { 
    const tick = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => { 
        tick.current = setInterval(() => console.log("mounted."), 1000);

        return () => {
        console.log("unmounted.");
            
        if(!tick.current) {
           //PopupActions.hide();
        } else {
           clearRef(); 
        }
    };
 }, []);

    const clearRef = () => {
        clearInterval(tick.current);
        tick.current = null;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            /* problem
            <button onClick={clearRef}>blahblah</button>
            */
        </div>
    );
}

export default testInterval;
```

when I quickly return to the original page from the prev page and click the button, the clearInterval func will not work intermittently and will continue to output the log "mounted"

Why is this a problem? And how can we solve this?

Comment: You'll need to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get useful answers. The first thing that comes to mind is that since you're using a `Ref` and not state the cleanup of the `useEffect` will not run onClick of the button, not sure if this is part of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't write it in the correct format.
I modified the code to a functional component! Thank you for the information :)